# Cookies do not work on my server

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with the cookies.
I have created a simple cookie and tried to echo it on my server.

```
setcookie('user', 'John', time() + 4800);
echo $_COOKIE['user'];
```

I also checked the value using the function **var_dump()** and the result is NULL.
I do not understand why :-(

Comment: Just refresh your page! Then the cookie is set

Comment: Hi, I also refreshed the page many times, but I cannot echo the cookie.

Comment: Check if you disabled cookies in your browser!

Comment: The cookies are not disabled.

Comment: Which browser do you use? And which version? Also did you checked the page infos? Also is this your entire code?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you cannot set a cookie in PHP and hope to retrieve the cookie immediately in that same script session. It will be available on the next request.

This doesn't mean that the cookie has not been sent, it just means you can't test it in the same script run.

Of course, before that, make sure that your cookies are turned on.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    setcookie('user', 'John', time() + 4800, '/');
    // set the cookie with the fourth parameter with root
    // so that its sitewide
} else {
    echo $_COOKIE['user'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Ghost, yes, of course. I am not trying to retrieve it in the same script session, but on the next ones...

Comment: @Daniel add `/` on the fourth parameter

Comment: I added / on the fourth parameter, but I am still having the same result :-(